# How to hide endpoint from outside the GKE cluster with GCE Ingress?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Imagine I have a "user-service" running in my GKE cluster with the following Ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'gce'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: 'false'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /users/*
            backend:
              serviceName: users-service
              servicePort: 12345
```

And in my users-service I expose some metrics on users-service/metrics. I would like to hide this /metrics endpoint from outside the cluster. Something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'gce'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: 'false'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /users/*
            respond:
              path: metrics
              status: 404
            backend:
              serviceName: users-service
              servicePort: 12345
```

So that whenever an outside client issues a request to example.com/users/metrics he gets a 404 response. Is this possible with the GCE Ingress?

Comment: Hi @user3217163, did you try add [annotation](nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:) `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:`? It could help you to deny access to the specific path. [Here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deny-access-some-specific-paths-while-using-ingress-oleksii-titarenko) is the good example how to use it.

Comment: Hi @MikołajGłodziak. I need to use the GCE Ingress, not the NGINX Ingress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple paths in your spec.  Requests will match the most specific path.
So you would have a path for `/user/*` and a path for `/user/metrics/*` in your spec.  GKE also provides a default backend service named `default-http-backend` which will return a 404.  Putting this all together, you'd have something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'gce'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: 'false'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /users/*
            backend:
              serviceName: users-service
              servicePort: 12345
          - path: /users/metrics/*
            backend:
              serviceName: default-http-backend
              servicePort: 80
```

With the above, anything sent to `example.com/users/metrics/*` should return a 404.

Comment: Nice. And would there be an easy way to do this for all /metrics of all services? Or must I specify this for each service?

Comment: Hmm ... off the top of my head I can’t think of a way ... but I’ll give it some thought